# AWS Elasticsearch indexing memory usage issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

The problem: very frequent "403 Request throttled due to too many requests" errors during data indexing which should be a [memory usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html#aes-troubleshooting-throttle-api) issue.

The infrastructure:

- Elasticsearch version: 7.8
- t3.small.elasticsearch instance (2 vCPU, 2 GB memory)
- Default settings
- Single domain, 1 node, 1 shard per index, no replicas

There's 3 indices with searchable data. 2 of them have roughly 1 million documents (500-600 MB) each and one with 25k (~20 MB). Indexing is not very simple (has history tracking) so I've been testing `refresh` with `true`, `wait_for` values or calling it separately when needed. The process is using search and bulk queries (been trying sizes of 500, 1000). There should be a limit of 10MB from AWS side so these are safely below that. I've also tested adding 0,5/1 second delays between requests, but none of this fiddling really has any noticeable benefit.

The project is currently in development so there is basically no traffic besides the indexing process itself. The smallest index generally needs an update once every 24 hours, larger ones once a week. Upscaling the infrastructure is not something we want to do just because indexing is so brittle. Even only updating the 25k data index twice in a row tends to fail with the above mentioned error. Any ideas how to reasonably solve this issue?

**Update 2020-11-10**

Did some digging in past logs and found that we used to have `429` `circuit_breaking_exception`-s (instead of the current `403`) with a reason among the lines of `[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [1017018726/969.9mb], which is larger than the limit of [1011774259/964.9mb], real usage: [1016820856/969.7mb], new bytes reserved: [197870/193.2kb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=0/0b, in_flight_requests=197870/193.2kb, accounting=4309694/4.1mb]`. Used [cluster stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html) to track memory usage during indexing, but didn't find anything that I could identify as a direct cause for the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up creating a solution based on the information that I could find. After some searching and reading it seemed like just trying again when running into errors is a valid approach with Elasticsearch. [For example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#multiple-workers-threads):

> Make sure to watch for TOO_MANY_REQUESTS (429) response codes
> (EsRejectedExecutionException with the Java client), which is the way
> that Elasticsearch tells you that it cannot keep up with the current
> indexing rate. When it happens, you should pause indexing a bit before
> trying again, ideally with randomized exponential backoff.

[The same guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_unset_or_increase_the_refresh_interval) has also useful information about refreshes:

> The operation that consists of making changes visible to search -
> called a refresh - is costly, and calling it often while there is
> ongoing indexing activity can hurt indexing speed.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second,
> but only on indices that have received one search request or more in
> the last 30 seconds.

In my use case indexing is a single linear process that does not occur frequently so this is what I did:

- [Disabled automatic refreshes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting) (`index.refresh_interval` set to `-1`)
- Using [refresh API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) and [refresh parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) (with `true` value) when and where needed
- When running into a "403 Request throttled due to too many requests" error the program will keep trying every 15 seconds until it succeeds or the time limit (currently 60 seconds) is hit. Will adjust the numbers/functionality if needed, but results have been good so far.

This way the indexing is still fast, but will slow down when needed to provide better stability.